# How to translate in German "This dessert is the best"

Tags: english-to-german, adjective

In a German lesson, I've come up with the sentence:

> Der Nachtisch ist das Beste

meaning that dessert is the best part of a meal. But what if I want to say: "This dessert is the best" (of all desserts). Would

> Dieser Nachtisch ist der Beste

be correct?

Comment: Yes, completely correct. "Dieser Nachtisch ist der Beste" is totally usual way to express this, especially in oral communication. In written communication you would probably choose a somewhat more circumstantial expression as suggested by Volker in an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your suggestion is correct.

> Dieser Nachtisch ist der Beste

is a totally usual way to express that this one dessert is (by the opinion of the speaker) the best from a selection of several.

You would use this especially in oral communication. An even more casual way of speaking would be

> Der da ist der Beste / Der Nachtisch da ist der Beste.

with emphasis on *der*.

In written communication you would probably choose a somewhat more circumstantial expression as suggested by Volker in his answer, which was:

> Dies ist der beste Nachtisch.

or

> Dies ist von allen der beste Nachtisch.

But in oral language in everyday situations this would sound a bit artificial.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to compare it to other desserts, the best way would be "Dies ist der beste Nachtisch (von allen)"